# Set ValidationMessage for each single property in ValidationContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, attributes

In cases when a validation attribute is required to be applied on the whole class, example:

```
[PasswordCheck]
public class PasswordModel{
    public String OldPass{get; set;}
    public String NewPass {get; set;}
    public String NewPassConfirm {get; set;}
}
```

How the ValidationContext can be used to set `ValidationMessages` for each member of the class, for example:

```
public class PasswordCheckAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        PasswordModel Model = (PasswordModel)value;
        if (!Model.NewPass.Equals(Model.NewPassConfirm)) {
            return new ValidationResult("Entered new password is not valid.");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above example does not set particular `ValidationMessage` for each specific property. What I am after is to set `ValidationMessage` for:

```
 NewPass
 NewPassConfirm
```

I'm sure the `ValidationContext` parameter can be used but not sure how exactly. Appreciate any guidelines.

Comment: Why would you not apply validation attributes to each property (e.g. `[Compare]` attribute for  `NewPassConfirm`) and get server and client side validation out of the box?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: from my point of view, applying the attribute to the whole class and then setting the validation messages would be more convenient.

Comment: Your applying the attribute to a class. How would you expect the `ValidationResult` to then be returned for a property? Not sure how losing client side validation is _more convenient_ or why you want to reinvent the wheel

Comment: @StephenMuecke: This is fully based on reflection as the ValidationContext can also be used to get values from the object. But my problem is I don't what property is responsible for posting back the Validation Messages and how it should be done. So "How would I expect ..": this is a normal procedure and I just found (moments before reading your comment) that the ValidationResult type has a parameter of type IEnumerable<String> that can be used for defining to which properties the error message is applicable. If it passes the test, will be posted as an aswer here.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: What exactly do you mean by client side validation, do you mean developing JS methods and using Regex validating right on the client side? If so although that may have some benefits, it also has some disadvantages.

Comment: Client side validation for validation attributes like `[Required]` and `[Compare]` come out of the box (by using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` and including the appropriate `jquery-validate` files. What possible disadvantages are there in informing your users that there is an error before submitting the form?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: If the what you are talking about validates the model according to the attribute on the client side, that is very interesting. But considering that validation is mainly for type checking and preventing garbage data, client side validation (to my knowledge) is vulnerable to side-scripting which allows an attacker to easy bypass the mechanism and fills up the db which rubbish data.

Comment: Its still validated on the server as well so there is no issue with invalid data

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I think there's been a misunderstanding (both you and me) I wanna post back the ValidationMessage to be caught using `@html.ValidationMessageFor()` so I think this server side as the data is validated on the server. But client side, there is no way using client side you can validate according the data models since the models are on the server. So what you are explaining to me is not client-side validation it is exactly the same thing I'm doing. I thought by client side you meant using JQuery or JS purely to validate fields.

Comment: I do mean mean client side validation. It's all ready built in using `jquery-validate.js` and `jquery-validate-unobtrusive.js`. If you use the html helpers to generate your controls, it add `data-val-` attributes to the html that are used by those files to provide client side validation (which prevents the form submitting until the errors are corrected). Then in the controller, server side validation is also performed and can be checked with `ModelState.IsValid`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: well that is very interesting I didn't know about it.

Comment: Create a new project in VS with FormsAuthentication, then look at the models and views associated with the Account Controller, in particular the `ManageUserViewModel` (for MVC-5) which seems to be exactly what you are doing

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Stephen I have posted a question which I think you might be able to answer, so please check it out if you have time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302884/mvc-5-2-2-0-scripts-render-not-recognized