# MVC 5.2.2.0: @Scripts.Render(...) not recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I've recently upgraded my Visual Studio to update 4 (2013) and apparently my MVC version has been upgraded as well. The problem is that, I can no longer use the `@Scripts.Render` because it does not recognize the `Scrripts` type and it says it does not exist. I know that it is from `System.Web.Optimization` but the `Optimization` namespace is also missing.

Why I'm using `@Scripts` is because of client-side validation and before this upgrade I had no issue with that. So is that a bug or has Microsoft made some changes to the new MVC version that this `Script.Render` method is no longer supported?

Comment: I don't have problems with mine -- it works the same after the update. It's probably a typo in this post but you have misspellings `Scrripts` and `Script.Render`. Are you having trouble with a new project or a pre-update project? Have you updated your packages with NuGet? Will it work if you use the full namespace `@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("...")`?

Comment: @Jasen: I've just read that System.Web.Optimization is now considered obsolete and that's why. We have to reference the Jquery now using HTML tags.

Comment: The NuGet package *Microsoft.Web.Optimization* may be out of date and has been replaced but the namespace and assembly *System.Web.Optimization* is still valid.

Comment: I can create a new MVC application -- using the built-in template, with my updated tooling and still use the bundling system as I always have.

Comment: @Jasen: Maybe the MVC template automatically does some config, I use the empty option and I make my own (old habit), but I just discovered that there is really no need for Optimization namespace anymore. The new features are way way better

Comment: If you use the empty template then you will have to manually add the optimization package [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/). The `@Scripts.Render` is still valid and it still bundles and compresses your resources like it always had. But if you have found an alternative then don't bother with it.

Comment: @Jasen: Yeah that is possible, but I think they discontinued that for a reason, I may post the answer to show how to do it the new way.

Comment: @DevArc - they have not discontinued it.. even in Update 4, the bundling and optimization is still there if you use the default template.